# Edge sendNativeMessage ETA?

Tags: microsoft-edge

I was curious if anyone knew if, or when Edge will support runtime.sendNativeMessage?  I tried to ask here but have seen no response at all.

https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/suggestions/14453850-edge-extensions-should-support-runtime-sendnativem

It seems like an important feature to not have... so I'm confused why its not even in there already.

Answer (score 0):

Support for extensions in Microsoft Edge is currently a work in progress. Presently, no timeline is available for the `runtime` portion, but the *Extension API Roadmap* does list it as [**in development**](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/documentation/extensions/extension-api-roadmap/).

A list of *currently supported* `runtime` APIs is [available online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/api-support/supported-apis#runtime).